# Обработка нажатий или жестов в Android

Tags: android, c#, xna, monogame

Пишу Android приложение на движке Monogame/XNA. Столкнулся с проблемой того, что не могу обрабатывать нажатия и жесты. Я читал про класс `TouchLocation`, но со свойством `Position` у меня возникают проблемы (Всегда в нулевой точке). Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить точку касания и статус скрола.

Comment: Покажите код, с которым проблемы.

Comment: @Эникейщик А что там показывать, я инициализирую переменую типа`TouchLocation` и читаю ее свойство `Position`

Comment: @Эникейщик Я уже понял свою ошибку в обработке нажатий, но вопрос по поводу жестов остается